# Llenar un ID del tipo unique con randomElement genera errores. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Tengo una tabla con 500 usuarios y quiero llenar otra tabla que tiene un campo user_id del tipo único, pero si pongo esto en el seeder

```
$ids = User::select('id')->get()->pluck('id');

'user_id' => $this->faker->unique()->randomElement($ids),
```

Me genera el error: **Maximum retries of 10000 reached without finding a unique value**

---

Entonces lo intento de estas formas, sin llamar a la colección de IDs de usuarios puesto que se que son 500

```
'user_id' => $this->faker->unique()->randomElement(1,500),
'user_id' => $this->faker->unique(true)->numberBetween(1,500),
'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
```

Con estas instrucciones inicia a llenarse la tabla pero "faker" NO respeta el unique() y coloca en el campo user_id de la tabla un ID que ya ha colocado antes y el script se detiene y genera el error: **Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'N' for key**.

---

Y también lo intenté así y nada

```
$max = 500;
for($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    'user_id' => $i,
}
```

Y en este ultimo caso el id se repite desde la primera iteración. La verdad no creí que me fuera a dar tanto problema este pequeño paso.

Gracias por sus comentarios...

---

Porque si hago un foreach me coge el primer valor y luego quiere volver a poner ese mismo valor ya usado??

```
// Con cualquiera de estos arrays 
$ids = Video::select('id')->get()->pluck('id');
$ids = Video::select('id')->get();

foreach ($ids as $id) {
   'user_id' => $id,
}
```

He buscado y probado muchísimas formas y no encuentro como hacer que el campo único no se repita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, después de muchas pruebas pude resolver el problema llamando al Factory que crea al user en el Factory que lo necesitaba.

```
'user_id' => User::factory(),
```

Cabe mencionar que en otras tablas necesitaba el user_id y tuve que cambiar el orden de llamada de los Seeders del DatabaseSeeder.

Aun estoy en la búsqueda del porque no funcionaron las otras formas que probé, pero al menos puedo continuar con el curso de Eloquent que estoy haciendo.